# What's the best way to implement a color cycling background?

Tags: java, processing, trigonometry

What's the best way to cycle the color of a background smoothly (as well as other things) using cos or sin in java, without using more than one file? I've tried using randomness and increasing each individual r, g, and b value separately to make this look kind of normal, but it's jittery, not smooth, and the colors are horrid. Right now, it's just plain white. I included only the necessary code, and I am using Processing 3.

```
//background
int bg1 = 255; //r
int bg2 = 255; //g
int bg3 = 255; //b

void draw() {
fill(bg1,bg2,bg3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the general idea down. It's a three-step process:

- **Step 1:** Declare variables at the top of your sketch.
- **Step 2:** Use those variables to draw your scene.
- **Step 3:** Change those variables over time.

This is the basic approach to create any animation in Processing. [Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) is a tutorial with more information.

Here is a small example that shows a window that cycles between white and black:

```
float c = 0;

float cChange = 1;

void draw(){

  background(c);

  c += cChange;
  if(c < 0 || c > 255){
    cChange *= -1;
  }
}
```

You would need to do something similar, but with 3 color values instead of 1. Note that I'm only changing the color by a small amount each time, which makes it appear smooth instead of jittery.

If you're still having trouble, please post an updated [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to use a sine wave as input rather than the sawtooth wave then you need to map your input (e.g. time) to some color range. For example:

1. every 2000 milliseconds value increases from 0 to 2.0
2. value ranges from -1 to 1.
3. the output of sin(value) ranges from -1 to 1.
4. map the output to a color range.

[map()](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) works well for mapping values, but you can also use [colorMode()](https://processing.org/reference/colorMode_.html) for mapping color ranges -- so rather than moving your sine output values around, just make your output 0-2.0 and set the max RGB or HSB value to 2.0 rather than 255.

Here are some examples, all running simultaneously in one sketch:

```
float val;
float out;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  val = TWO_PI * (millis()%2000)/2000.0; // every 2000 milliseconds value increases from 0 to 2PI
  out = sin(val);

  // white-black (256-0)
  pushStyle(); 
  fill(128 + 128*out); 
  rect(0,0,50,50);
  popStyle();

  // red-black (255-0)
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(RGB, 255);
  fill(255*(out+1), 0, 0);
  rect(50,0,50,50);
  popStyle();

  // hue rainbow (0-2)
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(HSB, 2.0);
  fill(out+1, 2, 2);
  rect(0,50,50,50);
  popStyle();

  // hue blue-green (3 to 5 / 9)
  pushStyle();
  colorMode(HSB, 9);
  fill(out+4, 9, 9);
  rect(50,50,50,50);
  popStyle();

  translate(width/2,height/2 - out * height/2);
  ellipse(0,0,10,10);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Don't understand what you mean by cos and sin in relation to background color.  But maybe something like this is what you want?

```
void draw(){
 int H = frameCount%1536;
 background(color(abs(H-765)-256,512-abs(H-512),512-abs(H-1024))); 
}
```